# How can I separate elements of a list provided as an argument into groups of 2 and then print it out

Tags: python-3.x

```
def display_scores(scores):
   list1 = [1]
   for items in list1:
      print("NAME   SCORE")
      print(*scores, sep = "\n")
```

Here's an example of an argument that could be used (["BOB", 1200, "ZAK", 8000, "ROB", 3000]) So the main thing I haven't figured out yet is how to separate the str(names) from the int(scores) in the list and to print it out underneath their respective columns so like the output for this one would look like

```
NAME   SCORE
BOB    1200
ZAK    8000
ROB    3000
```

But any kind of list in this format could be used as an argument. like ["ZOE", 500, "TOM" 1800]

Comment: Also why are you iterating over `[1]`? Shouldn't it be `for item in scores`?

Comment: Ah thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If it helped you either mark the question as duplicate or simply delete it